# How can I get the hundredth currency symbol?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I want to get the hundredth currency symbol for any currency code
For example **cents** symbol, **USD hundredth symbol => ¢**
I want to do that in **C#** or **JavaScript**.
Is there any map or build-in generic functionality to do that in C# or JavaScript? I already can do that with the currency symbol but not the **hundredth** currency symbol.
I want to get the symbol itself using the currency code.

Update:
My question is how not to do it manually, you can imagine how long it will take to collect all currency hundredth symbol and create the dictionary. I prefer if there is any library or map out there to use quickly.

Comment: Not all currencies will even have a symbol for 1/100 - there may be no sub-units at all or the sub-unit may have another factor like 1/1000. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies. There is also an [XML form of this](https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html), but it does not include the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Reference your last comment:

Define a dictionary

First, define a class like this

```
public class CurrencySymbols
{
    public string cur { get; set; }
    public string hundredth { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it to define dictionary like this:

```
        var currencySymbols = new Dictionary<string, CurrencySymbols>();
        currencySymbols.Add("USA", new CurrencySymbols { cur = "$", hundredth = "¢" });
        currencySymbols.Add("EU", new CurrencySymbols { cur = "€", hundredth = "¢" });

        foreach (var currency in currencySymbols)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currency.Key, currency.Value.cur, currency.Value.hundredth);
        }
```

How to access the value:

```
    var symbolNeeded = currencySymbols["EU"].cur; //For Euro

    var symbolNeeded2 = currencySymbols["EU"].hundredth; //For hundredth
```

Comment: I want to get the symbol itself using the currency code, not how to write it.

Comment: @Andrew Gergis according to your comment the answer updated.

Comment: @Andrew Gergis one more update added to show how to access the value.

Comment: @Andrew Gergis CurrencySymbols class definition has been added as well.

Comment: I get your point, My question is how not to do it manually, you can imagine how long it will take to collect all currency hundredth symbol and create the dictionary. I prefer if there is any library or map out there to use quickly.

Comment: @Andrew Gergis you have to build it manually

Comment: @Andrew Gergis this is simply because there is not formula in ascii table to find it as the symbol of

Comment: @Andrew Gergis  ¢ for example is applicable of Euro and USD

Comment: @Andrew Gergis and possibly many other currencies

Comment: @Andrew Gergis so either you do it like this, or you save them all in the Database table (slower)

Comment: @Andrew Gergis in real-life applications, this is hardcoded and placed in a static class or const class and called when needed.

Comment: @Andrew Gergis how called?! if the amount less than a specific amount use this symbol or use the amount/100 or /1000 as a decimal and attach the symbol at the beginning or end

Comment: @Andrew Gergis is this answered your question?

Comment: @Andrew Gergis you mention that they are big much but they are around 180 so it could be 30 minutes work.